# Python: numero con tres divisores

Tags: python

El programa me pide identificar si un numero tiene exactamente tres divisores, imprimir "SI" dado caso o "NO" para lo contrario. Ya intenté hacerlo de dos formas, sacándole raíz cuadrada al numero y verificar si es primo o usando un contador, pero de la primera forma me salen errores y en la segunda me sale que el tiempo excedió (el programa es muy lento, debe tardar 1 segundo). Tengo problemas específicamente con los siguientes números, lo de su derecha es lo que debería imprimir:

1. 16787607489 NO
2. 16787607483 NO
3. 16787607487 NO
4. 16787607485 NO
5. 16787607481 NO
6. 149573242009 SI
7. 25           SI
8. 9            SI
9. 3            NO
10. 11           NO

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería.

```
for casos in range(int(input())):
num=int(input())
cont=0
i=2
while i<num and cont<=1:
    resto=num%i
    if resto==0:
        cont+=1
    i+=1
if cont==1:
    print("SI")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Bienvenido Synth man c: Cual es el tiempo maximo que puede tardar el programa en saber si un numero es primo o no?

Comment: El tiempo que debe tardar es un segundo.

Comment: Según una calculadora online de numeros primos, el numero que te da problemas en la opción 6 no es primo. https://es.calcuworld.com/calculadoras-matematicas/calculadora-de-numeros-primos/

Comment: Sí, es que lo que se pide son los números con tres divisores. Los números con tres divisores son los números primos elevados al cuadrado, pero no sé cómo llevar eso a código...y que además tarde un segundo.

Comment: Tres divisores contando 1 y el propio numero?

Comment: Sí, exactamente.

Answer (score 3):

Para que un número tenga exactamente tres divisores y solo tres, ha de ser el cuadrado de un número primo. De ese modo los tres divisores son 1, el primo que es su raiz cuadrada, y el propio número.

Si no fuera así y tuviera otro divisor N distinto de la raiz cuadrada, eso significaría que el número es de la forma NxM, por lo que tendría un divisor más (M). Y si la raiz cuadrada no fuese un primo, tendría también más divisores (los factores de esa raiz).

Por tanto se le pueden realizar los siguientes tests al número:

1. ¿Tiene raíz exacta? De no ser así ya puedes responder NO
2. ¿Su raíz es un primo? Sólo en caso de que así sea responderás SI.

### Raiz exacta

Eso se puede comprobar truncando a entero el resultado de `sqrt()` y elevando eso al cuadrado, para ver si sale el mismo número.

```
def raiz_entera(numero):
   return int(math.sqrt(numero))


def tiene_raiz_exacta(numero):
   return raiz_entera(numero)**2 == numero
```

### Comprobación de si es primo

Para ver si un número N es primo probamos a dividirlo por 2, 3, 4, ... hasta haber probado todos los números inferiores o iguales a raiz de N. Tan pronto como encontremos un divisor podemos retornar `False` (no es primo). Sólo si agotamos el bucle retornaremos `True` (sí es primo).

```
def es_primo(n):
  i = 2
  while i <= raiz_entera(n):
    if n%i == 0:
       return False
    i+=1
  return True
```

**Nota** La función anterior aún se podría haber optimizado un poco probando solo los impares.

### Solución al problema

Armados con las funciones anteriores podemos escribir nuestro test:

```
def tiene_tres_divisores(numero):
  if not tiene_raiz_exacta(numero):
     return "NO"
  if es_primo(raiz_entera(numero)):
     return "SI"
  else:
     return "NO"
```

### Comprobación

```
numeros = [16787607489, 16787607483, 16787607487, 16787607485, 16787607481,
           149573242009, 25, 9, 3, 11]

for n in numeros:
  print(n, tiene_tres_divisores(n))
```

---

```
16787607489 NO
16787607483 NO
16787607487 NO
16787607485 NO
16787607481 NO
149573242009 SI
25 SI
9 SI
3 NO
11 NO
```

Tiempo total: 18.6 µs  (procesar la lista completa)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación.